# Test Automation tools shipped with Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise?

Tags: visual-studio, testing, tfs, testautomationfx

Management is looking into automated testing.  Our QA Lead would like to know what if any automated test tools are shipped with Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise and Team Foundation Server 2012.

From what I am reading, MS offers a Suite of Tools as a separate Product called Test Studio.  From what I can gather, there is nothing in Visual Studio itself or TFS itself to perform automated tests. Is this correct?

Won't they need Test Studio for this?  Or HP if they want to look at other vendors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manage your team’s code, build and test your apps, and plan and track your team’s work these can be achieved with Visual Studio and Team Foundation Server on your own server.

However, for test in TFS. TFS itself won't shipped with Test Automation tools. TFS use **Microsoft Test Manager**, a separate Team Foundation client, lets you manage and execute test cases and create and manage physical or virtual environments. **It installs with select Visual Studio editions.**

### Testing tools with VS

Visual Studio will include many powerful testing Tools and Services such as ***Load testing ,Continuous testing in DevOps,Manual testing,Exploratory testing,User acceptance testing,Unit testing and IDE***... More details please refer [Testing Tools and Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/testing-tools-vs.aspx)

If you want to quickly get started, here is also a help link  [Get started with developer testing tools](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/developer-testing/getting-started/getting-started-with-developer-testing)

### Overall Test Solution

If you need an overall Test solution, suggest you to use [Visual Studio Test Professional](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-test-professional-with-msdn-vs.aspx)

### Lisense

Moreover, also provide some license info for your reference: [Subscriber Benefits](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/subscriber-benefits-vs.aspx)

Comment: Thank you.  This is more or less the details I collected myself last night as well.  I am frustrated Microsoft is not making this more clear for everyone.  I have management here very confused as to what tool does what... And I don't blame them.