# Automated tests with TFS for Linux systems

Tags: linux, testing, tfs, automated-tests, mtm

My company is searching for a test management and test automation tool. Since we already use TFS 2015 for version control of our internal documents and product documentation, the question arose whether or not TFS is a suitable candidate for our testing needs.

Our situation is the following: We produce a software system that runs on our custom Linux-based OS, so all test systems are Linux machines. Each member of our test center has a personal Windows computer as well. We want test automation primarily for our functional tests, since our unit tests are already integrated into our build process.

I have done some research into this matter and found out that test management and manual testing should work quite fine with TFS via the Web Access. However, I cannot find reliable statements on the question whether or not the test automation via Microsoft Test Manager works with (remote) Linux machines.

So this is my question: Is there a way to use TFS and the Microsoft Test Manager to automate tests under Linux? If TFS itself cannot do this, are there integrations with external test automation frameworks?

For my research so far, I have used the following resources:

- the official documentation on testing with TFS
  https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/overview
- this official site on how to automate a test case with Microsoft Test Manager
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380741.aspx

I would appreciate any kind of help provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afraid not, **Install and Deploy test agent is not support in Linux System**.

> **What system requirements do I need to install my test  test agents?**
>
> - Windows 10
> - Windows 8, Windows 8.1
> - Windows 7 Service Pack 1
> - Windows XP Service Pack 3
> - Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2012 R2
> - Windows Server 2008 Release 2, Service Pack 1
>
> Source Link: [Install and configure test agents](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/lab-management/test-machines/install-configure-test-agents)

Features such as diagnostic data collection and functional test would not work on these machines since the test agent is not supported on those OSes.

More detailed info about TFS, MTM Test Management, Automation test, you can refer my answer in this question: [Test Automation tools shipped with Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38903953/test-automation-tools-shipped-with-visual-studio-2015-enterprise/38915207#38915207)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is quite like I expected.

It seems the only solution to the problem of using TFS for testing with Linux test systems is an integration of TFS or MTM with some test automation framework that works under Linux und using TFS just for test management and manual tests. I need to do some more research in this direction, but maybe you know if this scenario is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Per my view, we don’t have to run automation tests via TFS. You can use command line to run test. I guess you just want to reflect the test result in the TFS/build. If that’s the case, you can

1. Run your test under linux which will generate trx file
2. Publish the test result to the TFS/build. See 
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms243151(v%3dvs.140)