# Tesing in TeamCity VS TFS

Tags: testing, tfs, teamcity

Our team is about to start a project using visual studio.net. We haven't decided about solution manager yet.
**One of most important parts of our project is Testing**. I have worked with TFS before and I know it's so powerful in testing ([Link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/overview)). I don't have any idea how Teamcity deals with different type of testing. May you please let me know about your experience and point of view?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This question ([CruiseControl [.Net] vs TeamCity for continuous integration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195835/cruisecontrol-net-vs-teamcity-for-continuous-integration) ) has a lot of good answers about TeamCity. It does not only talking about test and do the compare to TFS, but it might shed some light on TeamCity for you.

TeamCity directly supports the following testing frameworks:

> **JUnit and TestNG for the following runners:**
>
> - Ant (when tests are run by the junit and testng tasks directly within    the script, TeamCity reports tests on the fly)
> - Maven2 (when tests are run by Maven Surefire plugin or Maven Failsafe    plugin, tests reporting occurs after each module test run
>     finish)
> - IntelliJ IDEA project (when run with appropriate IDEA run    configurations)
>
> **NUnit for the following runners:**
>
> - The NAnt (nunit2 task)
> - The MSBuild (NUnit community or NUnitTeamCity tasks)
> - Microsoft Visual Studio Solution runners (2003, 2005, 2008, 2010,    2012, 2013, and since Teamcity 9.1. Visual Studio 2015)
> - Any runner provided TeamCity Addin for NUnit is installed
>
> **MSTest 2005, 2008, 2010, 2012, 2013  and since Teamcity 9.1. MSTest 2015 (On-the-fly reporting is not available due to MSTest
>   limitations)**
>
> **VSTest 2012, 2013, 2015**
>
> **MSpec**

You can even custom Testing Frameworks if there is no TeamCity support yet for your testing framework, more details please refer the official documentation from Teamcity: [Testing Frameworks](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Testing+Frameworks)

For test in TFS. TFS itself won't shipped with Test Automation tools. TFS use Microsoft Test Manager, a separate Team Foundation client, lets you manage and execute test cases and create and manage physical or virtual environments. It installs with select Visual Studio editions.More info please see my answer in this [Test Automation tools shipped with Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38903953/test-automation-tools-shipped-with-visual-studio-2015-enterprise/38915207#38915207)

---

As for which one is better, it's hard to say.It still depends on the actual situation of your team. There are many factors affecting this such as: staff's knowledge structure, financial budget, test environment, training of develop tools  and so on.